# Is it safe to share a stream instance among multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

I have a set of keys.

```
class X {
  private static String[] keys = {"k1", "k2", ... };
```

I have to extract values for the keys from a request. I think I can use `map` to extract values and create a list necessary objects in some request processing method like this:

```
  public void processReq(Request req) {
    ...
    Stream.of(keys).map(k-> new Pack(k, req.getHeader(k)));
```

But creating `Stream` per every request looks unnecessary task. If sharing `Stream` instance among multiple threads is safe, I think I can modify the code like this:

```
class X {
  private static Stream<String> keys = Stream.of("k1", "k2", ...);
  ...

  public void processReq(Request req) {
    ...
    keys..map(k-> new Pack(k, req.getHeader(k)));
```

So, is sharing `Stream` instance among multiple threads like this safe?

Comment: This won't even work. A Stream can only be traversed once.

Comment: And creating a Stream over an array doesn't take any time. What takes time is to traverse it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams are not intended to be used more than once, even in the same thread.  If you want to have a collection, use a List (or an array)

```
 private static final List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("k1", "k2", ...);
```

This can be used multiple times.

```
List<Pack> packs = keys.stream()
                       .map(k-> new Pack(k, req.getHeader(k)))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In your code, the `new Pack` or `req.getHeader` is where most of the time is spent.

Answer (score 0):

No; it's not generally safe. ["Unless the source was explicitly designed for concurrent modification, unpredictable or erroneous behavior may result from modifying the stream source while it is being queried... A stream should be operated on only once."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)